# Transforming the array from the execute()

Tags: php

```
<?php

function hwthau_verify( $redr_userid, $loss_check )


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute( );
    $result = $stmt->fetchall( );
    $numk = count( $result['CERT_ID'] );
    $ary1 = array( );
    $value1 = each( $result );
    $value1 = $value1[1];
    $key = each( $result );
    $key = $key[0];

    while ( each( $result ) )
    {
        do
            $value = each( $value1 );
            $value = $value[1];
            $key1 = each( $value1 );
            $key1 = $key1[0];
            if ( each( $value1 ) )
            {
                $ary1[$key] = $value;
            }
        while(1)
    }

    $redr_type_code_first = $ary1['REDR_TYPE_CODE'];
    $redr_type_name = $ary1['REDR_TYPE_NAME'];
    $redr_flag = $ary1['REDR_FLAG'];
    $cert_flag = $ary1['CERT_FLAG'];
    $chk_validity_period = $ary1['CHK_VALIDITY_PERIOD'];
    $bgn_date = $ary1['BGN_DATE'];
    $end_date = $ary1['END_DATE'];
    $LocalDay = $ary1["TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')"];
    $password = $ary1['PASSWORD'];
    $str1 = $ary1['CERT_ID'];
    $PWD_CHECK_FLAG = $ary1['PWD_CHECK_FLAG'];
```

I want to make an API for authentication.but I have a problem.how to AS $result = $stmt->fetchall( ); transform the ary1 = array( );it's look like my code doesn't work . and I  don't know why he write that

```
  do
            $value = each( $value1 );
            $value = $value[1];
            $key1 = each( $value1 );
            $key1 = $key1[0];
            if ( each( $value1 ) )
            {
                $ary1[$key] = $value;
            }
        while(1)
```

it look like a closed loop。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use `foreach` instead of `while`?

you can use it like this:

```
<?php
foreach($result as $row){
  $redr_type_code_first = $row['REDR_TYPE_CODE'];
  $redr_type_name = $row['REDR_TYPE_NAME'];
  $redr_flag = $row['REDR_FLAG'];
  $cert_flag = $row['CERT_FLAG'];
  $chk_validity_period = $row['CHK_VALIDITY_PERIOD'];
  $bgn_date = $row['BGN_DATE'];
  $end_date = $row['END_DATE'];
  $LocalDay = $row["TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')"];
  $password = $row['PASSWORD'];
  $str1 = $row['CERT_ID'];
  $PWD_CHECK_FLAG = $row['PWD_CHECK_FLAG'];
}
?>
```